# Entity Framework saves connection string user ID to database instead of assigned value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, web, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 with Entity Framework, and SQL Server is the database server. I am getting the Active Directory username of the person logged into the web app, and I am trying to save that username to the database so that we can keep track of who makes changes to records.

However, instead of saving the username (like JMyers), it is saving the user ID that is configured in the SQL connection string.

Here is one of the functions where I save the username to the database:

```
public void UpdateEmployeeStatus(int employeeNumber, string lastName)
{
    string userName = GetADUsername(); //this function gets and formats the username.  The output would be something like JMyers

    PortalUser profileToUpdate = new PortalUser();

    // Get the profile that will be updated
    profileToUpdate = portalDb.PortalUsers
                              .First(u => u.EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber
                                          && u.LastName == lastName);

    if (profileToUpdate != null)
    {
        profileToUpdate.Active = false;
        profileToUpdate.AudtDate = DateTime.Now;
        profileToUpdate.AudtTime = DateTime.Now;
        profileToUpdate.AudtUser = userName;

        portalDb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the odd Date and Time fields storing the same value.  It's something weird that my employer wants.

All other fields save properly like the date, time, and Active flag.  When I run the debugger, the value of the `userName` variable is JMyers.  Also, the value of `profileToUpdate.AudtUser` is also JMyers.  However, the database somehow stores `un_BlahBlah` in the `AudtUser` field. That is the user ID in the connection string (I changed it in this post for security reasons).

[image]

Here is the connection string, with values, changed for security purposes:

```
"Server=Stark;Initial Catalog=Jarvis;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=un_BlahBlah;Password=MickeyMouse;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=true;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=90;"
```

The web app is also running in Azure as an App Service but the same behavior takes place both locally when I debug in Visual Studio, and when it's live in Azure.

Comment: You are using "Integrated Security=true" in the connection string which means you are using a windows credential (not username and password).  You should be getting the username and credentials and not from the connection string.

Comment: What is the definition of `PortalUser`, and what is the declaration of the underlying table (or view)?

Comment: @jdweng the weird thing is, I just realized I only have that Integrated Security setting in the connection string in the configuration settings in Azure.  I don't seem to have it in my connection string in the Visual Studio project.  I must have added it in Azure while troubleshooting.  Regardless, the problem still occurs locally without that setting.  Thanks though

Comment: @JeroenMostert PortalUser is a class that was generated by Entity Framework to mirror the portal_Users table in our database.  I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by the declaration of the underlying table.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ...` Both computed columns and triggers could gum up the works in terms of overriding/ignoring the value you pass into properties. It matters both what's in the class declaration in terms of attributes, and what's on the database end as the actual table.

Comment: From yunus ileri : *Can your table have a trigger?*

Comment: Assuming `GetADUsername()` does what it says, EF would never store the SQL account name. It's highly likely that the actual table column has a DEFAULT that stores `USER_NAME` or `CURRENT_USER`. Perhaps `AudtUser` isn't even mapped to the table.

Comment: I think you have a two port application at server.  1) Connection between client and server 2) Connection from server to database.  So at server you are probably using Authentication and the credentials from client/server connection is being used to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I dig some more digging & discovered there was a "Scalar-Valued Function" setup that took the value I pass it (JMyers) and changes it to JMyers instead of the un_BlahBlah that was in the connection string.

If it helps anyone in the future, this is the function that SQL was using:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_LogUserName] 
(
    @UserName nvarchar(25)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(25)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Current_System_User_Name NVARCHAR(255) = dbo.ufn_sys_getsystemuser()

    DECLARE @RetVal nvarchar(25)
    -- Declare the return variable here

    IF upper(@Current_System_User_Name) = 'WEB_API' OR upper(@Current_System_User_Name) like 'un_%' 
        BEGIN
        IF @UserName IS NOT NULL
            set @RetVal = @UserName
        else
            set @RetVal = @Current_System_User_Name
        END
    ELSE
            set @RetVal =  @Current_System_User_Name

    RETURN @RetVal

END
```

I appreciate everyone's feedback and suggestions.  It helped me dig through stored procedures, functions, and triggers to see what was happening.